# How to fix the boot loader to make Ubuntu 18.04 and an Acer Aspire

Tags: grub2, uefi, acer

Each time I start up my computer I get "System BootOrder not found intalizing defaults, creating boot order 0110 with label ubuntu for "EFI\ubuntu\shlmx64.efi" reset system.

I have tried 14.04 and 18.04 Ubuntu, both result in this error on boot. Both secure boot enabled and disabled failed.

CPU type is Intel Celeron CPU N3050 @ 1.60GHz
System BIOS version is v1.09.

Ubuntu is not at fault in this case, but rather the firmware has a bug. It was suggested that I attempt to install REfind, but essentially I would like to know how to fix this boot issue. Thanks